# Copy data from one existing row to another existing row in spark sql

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataset  **A** like .

```
+---------+---------+-----+
|price    |   status| id  |
+---------+---------+-----+
| null    | offline | 1   |      
|  3.4$   | online  | 2   | 
|  4.4$   | online  | 1   |
| null    | offline | 2   |   
+---------+---------+-----+
```

I want to make a new dataset **B** from **A** which will replace the **null** price values in **offline status** with the price in the **online status** row with same id.

My Expected output is

```
+---------+---------+-----+
|price    |   status| id  |
+---------+---------+-----+
|  4.4$   | offline | 1   |      
|  3.4$   | online  | 2   | 
|  4.4$   | online  | 1   |
|  3.4$   | offline | 2   |   
+---------+---------+-----+
```

How can I achieve the same?

Comment: JOIN, withColumn, dropColumn could work. Interesting id#

Comment: @thebluephantom Is there any sample code available? removed the # in id :)

Comment: I means id has multiple occurrences

Comment: @thebluephantom Ya .Its my scenario. id+status will be unique.

Comment: root
 |—Id: string (nullable =false)
 |—status: string (nullable =false)
 |—price:string (nullable = false)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with Window functions if you have unique pairs (status, id) by copying data this way

````scala
   val dfx: DataFrame = Seq(
      (Some(4), "online", 1),
      (None, "offline", 1),
      (Some(3), "online", 2),
      (None, "offline", 2)
    ).toDF("price", "status", "id")

   dfx.show()
     +-----+-------+---+
     |price| status| id|
     +-----+-------+---+
     |    4| online|  1|
     | null|offline|  1|
     |    3| online|  2|
     | null|offline|  2|
     +-----+-------+---+

    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, lag, coalesce}
    val windowPrice = Window.partitionBy(col("id")).orderBy("status")
    val dfx1 = dfx.withColumn("price2", lag(col("price"), -1) over windowPrice)
        .withColumn("correctedPrice", coalesce(col("price"), col("price2")))
        .drop("price", "price2")
    dfx1.show()
    ```
     +-------+---+--------------+
     | status| id|correctedPrice|
     +-------+---+--------------+
     |offline|  1|             4|
     | online|  1|             4|
     |offline|  2|             3|
     | online|  2|             3|
     +-------+---+--------------+
````

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can achieve it by using the below

```
    val input_df = List((null, "offline", "1"), ("3.4$", "online", "2"), ("4.4$", "online", "1"), (null, "offline", "2")).toDF("price", "status", "id")
    input_df.createOrReplaceTempView("TABLE1")
    spark.sql("""select case when a.price is null then b.price end as price, a.status,a.id from table1 a inner join table1 b on a.id = b.id where a.status <> b.status and a.price is null 
                 union all
                 select * from table1 where price is not null""").show()
```

output:

```
+-----+-------+---+
|price| status| id|
+-----+-------+---+
| 4.4$|offline|  1|
| 3.4$|offline|  2|
| 3.4$| online|  2|
| 4.4$| online|  1|
+-----+-------+---+
```

Answer (score 1):

Also just adding answer in Python Spark SQL with self join.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

values = [
  (None,"offline",1), 
  ("3.4$","online",2), 
  ("4.4$","online",1), 
  (None,"offline",2)
]

rdd = sc.parallelize(values)
schema = StructType([
    StructField("price", StringType(), True),
    StructField("status", StringType(), True),
    StructField("id", IntegerType(), True)
])

data = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)

data.show(20,False)
data.createOrReplaceTempView("data")

spark.sql("""
select case when a.price is null then b.price else b.price end as price,
       a.status, 
       b.id
from data as a inner join (select * from data where price is not null) b
on a.id = b.id
order by a.id
""").show(20,False)
```

Results:

```
+-----+-------+---+
|price|status |id |
+-----+-------+---+
|null |offline|1  |
|3.4$ |online |2  |
|4.4$ |online |1  |
|null |offline|2  |
+-----+-------+---+

+-----+-------+---+
|price|status |id |
+-----+-------+---+
|4.4$ |offline|1  |
|4.4$ |online |1  |
|3.4$ |online |2  |
|3.4$ |offline|2  |
+-----+-------+---+
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have `Dataset<Product>` of simple POJOs, I solved it with `groupByKey` and `flatMapGroups`. The Idea is the following:

1. group your Data by Id
2. In each group search for the product that has status online and get it's price
3. Return all products with adapted price

Here is the code:

```
Dataset<Product> transformed =
            data.groupByKey((MapFunction<Product, Integer>) product -> product.getId(), Encoders.INT())
                    .flatMapGroups(new FlatMapGroupsFunction<Integer, Product, Product>() {
                        @Override
                        public Iterator<Product> call(Integer integer, Iterator<Product> iterator)
                                throws Exception {

                            // get price
                            Double onlinePrice = null;

                            // prepare list to return
                            List<Product> emittedProducts = new ArrayList<>();

                            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                                Product next = iterator.next();
                                emittedProducts.add(next);
                                if (next.getStatus().equals("online")) {
                                    onlinePrice = next.getPrice();
                                }

                            }

                            Double finalOnlinePrice = onlinePrice;
                            emittedProducts.stream().forEach(p -> p.setPrice(finalOnlinePrice));

                            return emittedProducts.iterator();
                        }
                    }, Encoders.bean(Product.class));
```

Product ist just a POJO:

```
public static class Product implements Serializable

{
    public Double price;
    private String status;
    private int id;

    public Product(){}
    public Double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(Double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Setup:

```
    List<Product> p = new ArrayList<>();
    Product p1 = new Product();
    p1.setId(1);
    p1.setPrice(null);
    p1.setStatus("offline");

    Product p2 = new Product();
    p2.setId(2);
    p2.setPrice(3.4d);
    p2.setStatus("online");

    Product p3 = new Product();
    p3.setId(1);
    p3.setPrice(4.4d);
    p3.setStatus("online");

    Product p4 = new Product();
    p4.setId(2);
    p4.setPrice(null);
    p4.setStatus("offline");

    p.add(p1);
    p.add(p2);
    p.add(p3);
    p.add(p4);

    final Dataset<Product> data = spark.createDataset(p, Encoders.bean(Product.class));
```